# BottomNavigationView stuck at top

Tags: java, android, androidx

I've been trying to get a BottonNavigationView working. It just keeps sticking to the top of the layout and it's driving me nuts.

I've looked at Material Design Documentation for BottomNavigationView and it seems really simple, but I can't get it to work, https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation/. I even tried making a completely clean project where I tried it and the same thing happened.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_menu" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_black_24dp"
        android:title="Content"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/document"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_picture_as_pdf_black_24dp"
        android:title="Document"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmPgF.jpg)

Any ideas?

Comment: set gravity to bottom.
android:layout_gravity="bottom"

Comment: Just add => android:layout_gravity="bottom"  line to "com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend to use `ConstraintLayout` and set constraints in `Designer` tool. Will be easier if you are new in android world.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_bar_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I see, thank you, that works, how would I get it to work with a CoordinatorLayout. Not saying that's what I need, would just like to know.

Answer (score 2):

The gravity of your bottom navigation is set to start `android:layout_gravity="start"` changing it to `android:layout_gravity="bottom"` should work for you.